# Low FPS with images in a ListView

Tags: android, image, listview, scrollview, frame-rate

I'm making a App for the restaurant of my University.

I've a ScrollView with 2 ListView inside (one for the first dishes and the other for the second dishes).

I create the ListView with the next code:

```
ListView lista = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listaprimero); //first dishes
ArrayList<Plato> arraydir = new ArrayList<Plato>(); //array for first dishes

ListView listaS = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listasegundo); //second dishes
ArrayList<Plato> arraydirS = new ArrayList<Plato>(); //array for second dishes

Plato plato; //Object "dish"

//Now for each dish that I want to add, I use the object "Plato" 
//to create a dish with its photo and its name.
//Then I add it to the ArrayList

plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.macarrones), "Macarrones", "Amenizador");
arraydir.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arroz), "Arroz tres delicias", "CEO");
arraydir.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ternera), "Ternera", "Amenizador");
arraydir.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pollo), "Filetitos de pollo", "Directora RRHH");
arraydirS.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.merluza), "Merluza al horno", "Directora RRHH");
arraydirS.add(plato);

// I create the Adapter for the dishes
AdapterPlatos adapter = new AdapterPlatos(getActivity(), arraydir);
AdapterPlatos adapterS = new AdapterPlatos(getActivity(), arraydirS);

// Set it
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
listaS.setAdapter(adapterS);
```

Now, when I run the app I have very low FPS and Android Studio console says everytime: 
"Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

But when I create the dishes like this:

```
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.macarrones), "Dish 1", "Amenizador");
    arraydir.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.macarrones), "Dish 2", "Amenizador");
    arraydir.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.macarrones), "Dish 3", "Amenizador");
    arraydir.add(plato);
plato = new Plato(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.macarrones), "Dish 4", "Amenizador");
    arraydirS.add(plato);
...
```

With the **same photo**, no problems happens.

PD: The size of the photos are between 70 and 200Kb, not heavy files.

Why?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still takes time to decode and load that Drawable(Bitmap) into memory to display.

It would be better if your `Plato` object only held on to the resource id of the drawable, and not the drawable itself.  This will use a lot less memory.  Then in your adapter `getView()`, you can use something like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide%20Glide) to load that resource into your `ImageView`.

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.macarrones).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Perfect! Changing in "Plato" the drawable for the path to the pic and using Glide no problems of FPS :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the images are the right size for the container. Resizing images on the fly is costly computationally and results in slower app performance; specially when it comes to ListViews.

If you are getting the images from a server, or you are supporting different display sizes, you might consider having a background thread to resize them first and then use the resized ones instead of the originals (that need to be resized on the fly when assigned to the views).